# Can you send a status code and a html web page?

Tags: javascript, html, express, http-status-codes

I am using the express framework in node and I don't know what is best practice or if this is the wrong thing to do but I wanted to send a status code e.g. `res.status(200).send("Success");` if the form input matches with the server and if it does not match then send something like `res.status(403).send("Forbidden");` 
Then in the webpage I can update the paragraph element with the sent response. So the user knows if it has been successful or not.

Is this possible? If it is how do I do it? And is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For sure it is possible!**
Taken from the express api reference:

> **res.status(code)**
>   Sets the HTTP status for the response. It is a chainable alias of Node’s response.statusCode.

```
    res.status(403).end()
    res.status(400).send('Bad Request')
    res.status(404).sendFile('/absolute/path/to/404.png')
```

Generally sending status codes is the way to go. If you are sending data without a status code, express will add the 200 status code automatically, so you don't have to add it manually.

On the client side, you have to check for a non 2xx status code in your response object of your request. Here is an example using the fetch api.

```
    fetch('/your/api')
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) { // Check for a non 2xx status code
          throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
        // Do something with the response data
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // This is only reached when a network error is encountered or CORS is misconfigured on the server-side
        console.error('There has been a problem with your fetch operation:', error);
      });
```

---

**Example: Credentials Use Case**
If you want to write a web page which has a form to enter user credentials to gain access to further content, I would suggest doing it the following way:

- Client side:

```
    // Function is listening to the submit event of your login form
    function submitLoginForm() {
      let username = document.getElementById("username").value;
      let password = document.getElementById("password").value;
      const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      };
      return fetch('/api/login', options)
        .then((response) => {
          // Check for a non 2xx status code
          if (!response.ok) {
            // Show a failed login hint
            showMessageBox('Login was not granted by the server. Please check you user name or password and try again.', 'error');
          }
          // Your login was successfull, manually redirect to user's dashboard, or whatever content...
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // This is only reached when a network error is encountered or CORS is misconfigured on the server-side
          console.error('There has been a problem with your fetch operation:', error);
        });

    }
```

- Server side:

```
    app.post('/api/login', (req, res, next) => {
      let username = req.body.username;
      let password = req.body.password;
      checkCredentials(username, password, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(400).send('Wrong user name or password.');
        }
        // Consider adding a token or a cookie to the response object, so that the user keeps logged in.
        return res.send('Access granted.');
      });
    });
```

Comment: Hi noChance thanks for replying! I mean how do I send the html page when I am also sending the status of the webpage? Am I supposed to send them to different path? E.g. so in mine a form is used which sends a post request and then the server responds with sucess or forbidden. How do I respond with the html page? Do I send the html page to a different path and then have the client of that path fetch it? So that it updates the element depending on the sucess or failure of the response? Or do I make 2 webpages? One with sucess one with failure? I am not sure. Thank again!